# Several commands in one AWK code

Tags: bash, awk

I was wondering how to write an AWK code that:

1. Replaces `\n_ _ _` with `;_` (Each `_` is a whitespace)
2. Finds a pattern and only print all the lines with that pattern

So far I have done is:

```
awk -vRS="\n   " -vORS="; " '1' '/^C1 / {print $0}' file
```

**The input**:

```
AU Luna, J
   Plata, M
C1 [Luna, Joaquin; Gonzalez, Mauricio] Inst Nacl Cancerol, Bogota, Colombia.
   [Plata, Manuel] Fdn Cardioinfantil, Bogota, Colombia.
```

**The output**:

```
C1 [Luna, Joaquin; Gonzalez, Mauricio] Inst Nacl Cancerol, Bogota, Colombia.; [Plata, Manuel] Fdn Cardioinfantil, Bogota, Colombia.
```

Comment: please post an example file (and optionally the expected result). It is more easy for people who take the time to help you, to make some test.

Comment: Could you please rephrase that question so it doesn't involve special characters? i.e. ask for replacing "aaa" with "bbb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your file is:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

And you want a single awk command to:

1. substitute `aaa` with `bbb`
2. print all lines matching the regexp `[bc]`

Something like this could work:

```
gawk '{ gsub(/aaa/, "bbb") } /[bc]/ { print }' file
```

Comment: Yes, it properly works :D. Last question, if I may, Can you advice me how to think programming in awk?. I used to write codes in bash. Thanks in advance ( :

Comment: AWK is simply `condition { statements }`. Conditions can be special such as `BEGIN` or `END`. I suggest reading the man page, which is not too long. Also, playing with it makes you feel more confident :)

Comment: @Alejandro I've made it even simpler. Apparently `gsub()` modifies `$0` so no need to store the return value anywhere.

Comment: You don't need `{ print }`, that's the default behavior. I don't understand how this answer actually answers the posted question though as you cannot use this approach to join lines and print the result.

Comment: @EdMorton his question was confusing and the focus was on "Several commands in one AWK code". That's what I answered. Didn't know about `{ print }` being redundant. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'sub(/^ +/,"; "){if (p ~ /^C1/) print p $0} {p=$0}' file
C1 [Luna, Joaquin; Gonzalez, Mauricio] Inst Nacl Cancerol, Bogota, Colombia.; [Plata, Manuel] Fdn Cardioinfantil, Bogota, Colombia.
```